# is unobstrusive javascript style slower than the usual?

Tags: javascript, jquery, unobtrusive-javascript

At the moment I'm doing jquery like this

```
<input id='aa' ... >
<script>
makeIt('aa', 2,'home/getitems',10)
</script>
```

I can also do it like this

```
<input class='theOne' ae-minLen='3' ae-url='home/getitems' ae-maxRes='10' ... >
```

and the `makeIt` is called on document.ready for 
`$(document).find('.theOne').each ...`

and it gets the values using

`$(this).attr('ae-minLen')` etc.

but, I'm wondering whether the unobtrusive way is slower than the usual ?

**EDIT:**
ppl say it's slower, how much slower is it, should I have a 5MB html to actually notice it ?

Comment: slower does not mean you should not use it. If the difference is mere milliseconds, there is really no reason to drop something that is much easier to write or change later, sometimes it can save hours of work.

Comment: I like the first way better, because you just have to get the ID to the elements. The other code, you have to go though the whole document and that's surely slower. I also don't find the first way obtrusive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes the unobtrusive way is the slowest, and will always be.

The question is weather or not this is relevant.

If you way the pros and cons, you will see that in most cases, the unobtrusive way will give you a lot of benefits (for instance easier maintainability of your code) for a very little performance cost.

[Read up on when to optimize](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_optimization#When_to_optimize)

Answer (score 3):

Do it the right way (unobtrusive).  Then, if you notice it is not fast enough, try it the other way and measure to see if it solves your problem.

Comment: I don't want to do stuff that is going to make it work slower

Comment: @Omu this is not the stuff that will make your program slow